# Jquery variable inside MVC4 on get method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am finally make progress in my code but now I have a small issue that can be better shown with this code below

```
<script>
 $(".mee").click(function (e) {
           var getID = $(this).attr("id");
  //I want getID passed inside the Url Action
            $.get('@Url.Action("ViewResponse", "thread", new {Model.Response= ?? })',   function (data) {
            $("#resultpost_"+getID).html(data).show();
         });
 });
</script>
```

If you look at the code above I have a jquery variable **getID** which holds the value that I need passed inside the mvc4 helper **Url.Action** specifically I want the **Model.Resonse**  to equal **getID** but I can't pass a jquery variable inside the action method how can I work around that ? and my code inside the page is in a foreach that is why I am using Jquery because the value changes depending on what the user clicks.

Here is what the action method looks like

```
 public PartialViewResult ViewResponse(PostResponse response,int responses_ThreadpostID)
    {
        response.ThreadpostID = responses_ThreadpostID;
            return PartialView("_ResponseView");
    }
```

So basically the **Get** method passes the value to the PartialView and from there the partialView will retain that value.

Comment: Coul you show your action code please?

Comment: Yes just post the action code on the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well what you trying to achieve, you can edit first your `Action` to pass only the `int` instead of the model that you don't use like this.

```
public PartialViewResult ViewResponse(int responses_ThreadpostID)
{   
    PostResponse response = new PostResponse();
    if(responses_ThreadpostID!=0)
    response.ThreadpostID = responses_ThreadpostID;
        return PartialView("_ResponseView",response);
}
```

And in your partial view you must make sure that the model correpsonds to the model passed.

And for your javascript function, you can have something like this:

```
<script>
$(".mee").click(function (e) {
       var getID = $(this).attr("id");
//I want getID passed inside the Url Action
        $.get('@Url.Action("ViewResponse", "thread")', {responses_ThreadpostID=getID  })
         .done(function(data) {
           $("#resultpost_"+getID).html(data).show();
         });
 });
</script>
```

I hope it will help you. Tell me if there is something wrong in case